# Heavy Flickering with RajawaliSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, google-project-tango, rajawali

I am working on an Android application with Googles Project Tango. As in the Plane Fitting [Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/java_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/java/com/projecttango/examples/java/planefitting/PlaneFittingActivity.java) from Google I use Rajawali Renderer.

When I start the activty for the fist time everything works fine. But when i resume from another activity heavy flickering starts. You can see this in this video: https://youtu.be/bn5jeTJEtq4

I use the Tango Development Tablet with Android 4.4.2. I tried already RajawaliSurfaceView and RajawaliTextureView. The problem exists with both.

Can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong or where the flicker comes from?

Comment: Just to get more information, are all the UI text drawn in Rajawalli? or that's another UI element from Android UI?

Comment: No, the text is on different UI elements. Basically its a toolbar and a RajawaliSurfaceView. The bar on the right is a Linear Layout with Buttons that is over the SurfaceView (sometimes its hidden and sometimes visible). The strange thing is that this flickering is also sometimes if the activity with the surfaceview is just in the background.

Comment: I've seen this in the past, I'm trying to remember what could have caused it and what was the solution. Does this happen with any of the samples just as they are in the samples repo, or only after you add some things to it?

Comment: I just tried with the planefitting example from github and there are no problems. However there are no nested views and no other acitvities are started. I could try to modify the example to see if I get the same output.

Comment: It would help finding the cause if you do that. My suspicion is that the problem is a delicate timing issue that happens between the connection to the Tango service and the starting of the OpenGL thread where the surface view is.

Comment: Ok, now I used the basic example from google and just added an option in the menu bar to start a second acitvity. When coming back from the 2nd activity, the plane_fitting_example behaves weird as well. Any Idea wo to deal with that?